# AWS beanstalk EC2 instance within a VPC and without Load Balancing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am creating the first betas of a project. I need a SpringBoot server connecting to MongoDBs in AWS.

MongoDB is already deployed as a replicaset in different EC2 instances. I was exploring AWS Beanstalk as environment to deploy the SpringBoot. However I am not yet ready to deploy a Load Balancer, because is costly.

I am looking for the way to deploy a Single-Instance Environment (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-types.html?ref_=pe_395030_31184250_9#single-instance-environ) in a VPC (which would be shared with MongoDB).

Does AWS Beanstalk allows you to configure a EC2 instance within an VPC but without Load Balancer?

If not, I am planning to deploy an EC2 instance in the VPC myself without Beanstalk.

Other temporary solution would be accessing MongoDB over the internet, with the right security group rules, but i do not think is a good practice at all, so I am not considering it.

Answer (score 0):

All Elastic Beanstalk environments are in a VPC, unless you have a really old AWS account that still supports EC2 classic. What you are looking for is the EB [Single-Instance Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-types.html) type.